# Howto pass flag to nvcc compiler in CMAKE

Tags: cmake, cuda, nvcc

I have a C project in `Cmake` in which I have embedded `cuda` *kernel module*.

I want to pass `--ptxas-options=-v` only to `nvcc` in-order to view 
*Number of registers usage per thread* and 
*shared Memory usage per block*.

By searching on howto pass flags to `nvcc` in `Cmake`, I came across a solution

```
add_compile_options(myprog
    PRIVATE
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:-Wall>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-arch=sm_20 -ptxas-options=-v>
)
```

but this didn't show me the above properties. I think these flags aren't passed to `nvcc` properly.

How can I pass `--ptxas-options=-v` to my `nvcc` compiler ?

Comment: I think you are looking for [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html), not [add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html).

Comment: target_compile_options(myprog PUBLIC $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:--ptxas-options=-v>) worked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The proper way to set CUDA flags **only on a target** is

```
target_compile_options(<my_target> PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:my_cuda_option>)
```

This will set the option, via the generator expression, only for files which are compiled for the CUDA language.

Using `CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS` as suggested by the other answer sets a global property for all targets, which might or might not be the right approach depending on the use-case.

Comment: This answer is much more precise, setting CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS is a kludge

Answer (score 17):

The newer approach of cmake cuda sets some other variables. Check the [docs here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-for-languages).

What we need is to set [CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html), which actually `CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS` here.

```
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} --ptxas-options=-v")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about?...

```
find_package( CUDA REQUIRED )
set( CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}" "--ptxas-options=-v" )

include_directories( ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
cuda_add_library( kernel_lib ${sources} )
```

You can check also the CMake CUDA documentation online... https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html

Comment: Make sure you are compiling with the cuda__add ... target commands.

Comment: You should also think about breaking up your CMakeLists.txt file.  You have a lot of stuff in there.  Consider sending some stuff to /config directory, and adding subdirectory - separating the C and CUDA code into separate directories is a good idea here.